# How can I compile my shader code to SPIR-V for Vulkan within Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, shader, vulkan

I am currently learning to use Vulkan and Visual Studio. I wrote vertex and fragment shaders in glsl and I am trying to compile them into SPIR-V code using a .bat file. I have set the script to open using PowerShell inside of the Visual Studio project, however when I run it, no .spv files are created. If I run the script in File Explorer, the two shaders get compiled, but not in Visual Studio. For now I just explicitly added the compiled codes to the project, but I want to be able to compile them within VS so I don't have to keep adding them as I play around with the shaders. I am pretty new to IDEs, and I'm still trying to figure out how Visual Studio's solutions work and how they relate to the actual files in the program. I am using VS Community 2022.

The scripts are just calls to a function glslc.exe that compiles the shader code.

```
C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.224.1/Bin/glslc.exe shader.vert -o vert.spv
C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.224.1/Bin/glslc.exe shader.frag -o frag.spv
```

The Powershell is closing before I can see any output to it. Could it be an issue with that instead of VS?

Comment: Without seeing the scripts, VS settings, console output, or anything else, there isn't much we can do. At the very least, you ought to be able to verify that the scripts are being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try targetting the absolute path:

```
C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.224.1/Bin/glslc.exe C:/output/path/shader.vert -o vert.spv
C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.224.1/Bin/glslc.exe C:/output/path/shader.frag -o frag.spv
```

It's possible the script is started with a different working directory when it's executed by Visual Studio. You should also have `@echo on` (default behavior) at the top of your batch file, to make sure errors are printed (if any).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this [link](https://github.com/vblanco20-1/vulkan-guide/blob/all-chapters/CMakeLists.txt) can help you. We can achieve this by adding a shader project in CMake and then whenever you have a new shader and dont want to open the File Explorer to rerun `shadercompile.bat`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).